# elasticsearch bool query add logic

Tags: elasticsearch

```
$params = [
        "size" => 5000,
        'index' => 'my_post',
        'type' => 'my_post',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        [

                            'match' => ['poststatus_id' => 'public']
                        ],
                        [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    "match" => [
                                        'poststatus_id' => 'only_me',
                                    ],
                                    "match" => [
                                        'creator.user_id' => $user
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]


                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

**its my elastic search query i Need another or condition that is 
poststatus_id = "followers" and creator.user_id in (1,2,3,4)
anyone tell me how can i write this query**

Comment: you need to use a terms query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html . BTW i think you should use a term query instead of a match query for your condition on poststatus_id and creator.user_id

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$params = [
        "size" => 5000,
        'index' => 'my_post',
        'type' => 'my_post',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        [

                            'match' => ['poststatus_id' => 'public']
                        ],
                        [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    [
                                        "match" => [
                                            'poststatus_id' => 'only_me',
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "match" => [
                                            'creator.user_id' => $user
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    [
                                        "match" => [
                                            "poststatus_id" => "followers"
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "terms" => [
                                            "poststatus_id" => [1,2,3,4]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = [
        "size" => 5000,
        'index' => 'my_post',
        'type' => 'my_post',
        'body' => [

            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        [

                            'match' => ['poststatus_id' => 'public']
                        ],
                        [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    "match" => [
                                        'poststatus_id' => 'only_me',
                                    ],
                                    "match" => [
                                        'creator.user_id' => $user
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]


                        ],

                        [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    [
                                        "match" => [
                                            "poststatus_id" => "followers"
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "terms" => [
                                            "creator.user_id" => [1,2,3,4]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],

        ]
    ];
```